# How to install Visual Studio? There are so many errors

Tags: visual-studio

I have tried to install vs_community_ENU.exe two times, but the installer terminates with many errors.  There is also a detailed log: http://pasted.co/1fee3d17 [image]

Comment: You can use a service like PasteBin to get the log to us.  Post the error log there then edit your question to add the link it gives you.

Comment: Who knows?  Read the detailed log.  It's going to start listing errors sometime.  Start with the first one.  It's probably the most important one anyhow.  Try problem solving rather than trying the same thing over and over again then asking for help here.  If you keep doing that, you're going to get question banned quick.

Comment: @Bradley, good idea.  Pastebin could not handle the log size, but I found one that did.

Comment: @Will, the errors are just plain weird.  I can't make anything of them.  I downloaded a 2MB installer that spent ages sucking stuff off the web, and then it just stops.  I just found an ISO image that I can use instead of the downloader, so that just might do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately the error log just seems to be full of `Return Code:0x0 Msi Messages:There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.   Result Detail:0 Restart:None` on the different component MSIs without any usefyl looking information.  I don't really know where to go from there.

Comment: Your internets suck and the downloaded installer was corrupt.  Use the ISO.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.  I gave up on the online installer vs_community_ENU.exe (size 211K) and instead installed vs2015.com_enu.iso (size 3.9GB)

The online installer must have bugs.  Not my problem!